# Compression of a spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

I find the following situation: I have a spring with constant $k$ that meets a mass $m$ at one of its ends, which is elongated at a distance $L$ from the equilibrium point as shown in the figure.

[image: Spring]

If I place my reference system so that the equilibrium position is at the origin and we release the mass, it will rise in the direction of the $y$ axis and reach a small height above the equilibrium position, my question is How can I deduce how high above equilibrium it reaches?

The total work done by the spring and by gravity to bring the end L to the equilibrium position is $W=\cfrac{kL^2}{2} -mgL$, but I don't know if it works for me, I calculated something but not It sounds logical to me, and it is that the height it reaches is: $h = - \cfrac{2mg}{k}$, could someone explain to me how to get to that height value, because I am very suspicious of my result?

Comment: "It will rise in the direction of the x axis". So the x axis is in the vertical direction? Place your coordinate system on your picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose an ideal spring and neglect the effect of air resistance.

Apply: $\sum F = m \vec{a}$.

You have tree equilibrium points ($\sum F = 0$):

$x_{0}$ when there is no external force:

\begin{equation}
F_{g}+F_{k}=0
\hspace{5pt} \Leftrightarrow \hspace{5pt}
x_{0}=\dfrac{mg}{k}
\end{equation}

$x_{i}$ when the spring is streched:

\begin{equation}
F_{g}+F_{k}+F_{ext}=0
\hspace{5pt} \Leftrightarrow \hspace{5pt}
x_{i}=\dfrac{mg+F_{ext}}{k}
\end{equation}

$x_{f}$ when the mass stops above $x_{0}$:

\begin{equation}
F_{g}=F_{k}+F_{ext}
\hspace{5pt} \Leftrightarrow \hspace{5pt}
x_{f}=\dfrac{mg-F_{ext}}{k}
\end{equation}

Where:

- $F_{g} = mg$ is **Newton's law**.
- $F_{k} = -k\cdot \Delta x$ is the **Hooke's law**. For short, when the spring is without mass $\Delta x = x_{0} - x_{rest} = x_{0}$.
  In the equilibrium $x_{f}$ this term is: $F_{k} = -k\cdot \Delta x' = -k\cdot (x_{rest}-x_{f}) = -k\cdot(-x_{f})$
- $F_{ext}$ is the **external force**.

If the reference system has the origin in $x_{0}=\dfrac{mg}{k}$ so that $x'_{0} = 0$, the other equilibrium points will be $x'_{i} = x_{i} - x_{0}$ and $x'_{f} = x_{f} - x_{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you're describing the case where the equilibrium position is the mass hanging at rest, with the spring stretched out somewhat due to gravity, and the mass is pulled farther downward by a distance $L$ and then released.** This case resembles a spring-mass-damper problem, in which damping can arise in the mechanical deformation of the spring (termed internal friction or hysteresis) and in air resistance, among other effects. The spring is considered to be massless. The amount and type of damping determine the amount of overshoot. **If damping is considered negligible, then the released mass oscillates between $L$ and $-L$**, as shown below.

I survey how to solve spring-mass-damper problems using integral transforms [here](http://john.maloney.org/Programming/pythonboing.htm). If the [damping increases linearly with the speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashpot), termed [Stokes drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Very_low_Reynolds_numbers:_Stokes%27_drag), for example, then Newton's Second Law gives $$m\ddot x=-c\dot x-kx,$$ where $c$ is the damping coefficient and $k$ is the spring constant. If $c=0$, then the solution is $$x=L\cos\left(\omega_n t\right),$$

where $\omega_n=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$. This is a sinusoid with an amplitude that matches the initial displacement $L$ from the equilibrium point. [As $c$ increases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio), we move from underdamping to critical damping to overdamping. At the critical damping level $c=2\sqrt{km}$ and above, there is no overshoot. Below this value, we do see overshoot, and the equation of motion above is solved to give $$x=L\exp(-z\omega_n t)\left[\cos(\omega_d t)+\frac{z}{\sqrt {1-z^2}}\sin(\omega_d t)\right],$$ where $\omega_d=\omega_n(\sqrt{1-z^2})$, with $z=c/(2\sqrt{km})$, the critical damping ratio.

Other types of damping could also exist (e.g., [air drag that scales up with the square of the speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#At_high_velocity), which would result in a different solution.

**Another reading of your problem is that the mass is removed at a displacement $L$, and the (massless) spring returns to its original point.** This is also solved in my link as $$x=L\exp(-kt/c).$$ If the damping is small, then the spring returns to its unstretched length very quickly. No overshoot occurs for a massless spring; overshoot requires inertia.

Finally, if it's important to consider the mass of the spring, this is often done by [considering an additional mass at the end of the spring that equals a third of the spring's mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(spring%E2%80%93mass_system)). The solution is then as described above with this additional mass. Does this all make sense?

Answer (score 0):

@*Kami* I think I understand the experiment you are performing. I'm guessing you are taking a massless unextended ideal spring (plus no frictional forces) and then adding mass and letting it drop. It drops a total distance of L due to gravity before the restoring force of the spring stops the motion and then the whole thing will keep oscillating around the center i.e. L/2.

The solution as I see it is to consider that when the spriing is fully extended, its potential energy (work stored in the spring) is $1/2*k*L^2$. When the restoring force of the spring works its magic, it moves the mass through the gravity field up through a potential that is $m*g*L$. At the top and the bottom the velocity is zero and so the kinetic energy is zero at both endpoints, meaning at the top and the bottom all the energy is stored potential and the same at both ends. We therefore have an equality between conditions at the top and the bottom of the traverse. This means
$$ 1/2*k*L^2 = m*g*L$$
Solving for L gives your proposed solution. Just remember the solution oscillates around a center point L/2 with you "0" being your initial position for the drop and "L" being the maximum extension. As @*Chemomechanics* pointed out assuming no friction the period of the oscillation will be independent of L and have an angular frequency of $\sqrt{k/m}$ .